# Overwrite layer of hosted feature service but not related table in Python

Tags: python, arcgis-online, update, feature-service

I have a hosted feature service with a related table. The layer in the feature service needs to be updated every month or so. However, the data in the related table needs to remain unchanged. Is there a pythonic way to update the layer without altering the related data? I looked at [creating an .sd file](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/createmapsddraft.htm) with Python but I don't anticipate much success based on what testing I've done. Would deleting the layer's contents and updating through the REST be feasible when I'm dealing with +70 thousand spatial objects?

Comment: Here is a similar question on ESRI's Geonet. [Overwrite only layer and attributes of a feature service and not the related table and attachments?](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/194405-overwrite-only-layer-geometry-and-attributes-of-a-feature-service-and-not-the-related-table)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you'll need to create a separate .mxd file with nothing more than the feature you'd like to update in it.  Then, from that new .mxd file, publish a feature service.  After that initial push, use [this python script called update-hosted-feature-service](https://github.com/khibma/update-hosted-feature-service) to overwrite the hosted feature service as you schedule it to run.

Comment: If I'm understanding the script correctly, it would update the entire feature service, which I don't want to do. I only want to update a part of the feature service, the individual layer, while leaving the table unchanged.